# How to get the integer index in python?

Tags: python

I want to split data. But when I print training it says that split_index should be integer. My sample and split_index both are integers then where should I need integers?

```
sample = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
print sample
print len(sample)
split = 0.7
split_index = floor(len(sample)*split)
print split_index
training = sample[:split_index]
print training
```

Comment: split_index = int(floor(len(sample)*split))

Comment: math.floor(x)
Return the floor of x as a float, the largest integer value less than or equal to x.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor
sample = np.arange(10).reshape(10, 1)
print sample
print len(sample)
split = 0.7
split_index = int(floor(len(sample)*split))
print split_index
training = sample[:split_index]
print training
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Use the built in tools in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

[`floor()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) returns a float.

> Return the floor of x as a float, the largest integer value less than or equal to x.

So for example:

```
>>> floor(5.2)
5.0
```

You need to convert your floored value to an integer.

```
split_index = int(floor(len(sample)*split))
```